# Database drivers specification in code

Tags: c#, python, sql, sql-server, oracle

Good morning all,

recently I came upon problem with DB connection in Python and C#.

For example, let's say we want to connect SQL Server. In .NET (C#) we just need to know the server name, credentials and we can connect to DB with `SqlConnection` object. That's clear.

Now, in Python, when using `pypyodbc` we need to specify driver additionally. And here's come the question:

Why in Python we have to specify driver? We don't have to specify it in C#.

On the other hand, if specifying driver is so crucial, then why don't we have to specify it in C#?

I know, that in C# we have dedicated class for SQL Server (does Python? or `pypyodbc` is the only choice?), does that mean, that it has some method to resolve which driver to use? Is it the same with Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about python, but I think that should answer your main question:

`SqlConnection` is designed specifically to work with SQL server, so you don't need to specify the driver, because it uses it's own designated driver.
From [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2) page on Microsoft docs:

> The ConnectionString is similar to an OLE DB connection string, but is not identical. Unlike OLE DB or ADO, the connection string that is returned is the same as the user-set ConnectionString, minus security information if the Persist Security Info value is set to false (default). **The .NET Framework Data Provider** for SQL Server does not persist or return the password in a connection string unless you set Persist Security Info to true.

(Emphasis mine, other stuff in the quot are just to provide context.)

And later on down the page:

> The **.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server** uses its own protocol to communicate with SQL Server. Therefore, it does not support the use of an ODBC data source name (DSN) when connecting to SQL Server because it does not add an ODBC layer.

(again, emphasis mine.)

When working with other connection classes such as [`OdbcConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [`OleDbConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2), you need to specify the driver in the connection string.

With [Odbc Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax#odbc-connection-strings) use the keyword `Driver`,
and with [OleDb Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax#oledb-connection-strings) use the keyword `Provider`.

About Oracle, The .Net framework have a namespace called `System.Data.OracleClient`, but it's deprecated (from [Oracle and ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet)):

> The types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated. The types remain supported in the current version of.NET Framework but will be removed in a future release. Microsoft recommends that you use a third-party Oracle provider.

I'm guessing Oracle's own ADO.Net implementation also works with it's own driver. If you really want to know, you can look it up in their documentation.

Comment: Your assumption is right: For `System.Data.OracleClient` and Oracle's own ADO.Net implementation (i.e. `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` and `Oracle.DataAccess`) you don't have to specify any driver.